# HTACCESS PUZZLE! Why does "?" work in one Rewrite statement and doesn't in another? See example

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I've been working on htaccess since like yesterday. I have two Rewrite statements in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^.*wp-login\.php\?loggedout=true.*$ /not_found [R,L]
```

The above statement works. While

```
RewriteRule ^.*wp-login\.php\?action=login.*% /not_found [R,L]
```

...doesn't!

To make the second case work, I used the following statements.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=logout

RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ /not_found/? [R,L]
```

So, not using "?action=logout" in the RewriteRule in the second case seems to solve the problem.

Yes, the problem is solved, but I'd like to understand why. This is so puzzling.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your earlier rules are incorrect because `QUERY_STRING` cannot be matched in `RewriteRule`. `RewriteRule` only match request uri without query string.

So correct rules are:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)action=logout(&|$)
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ /not_found/? [R,L]
```

OR this to include both query parameters:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)action=(login|logout)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ /not_found/? [R,L]
```

Comment: Before reading your answer, I have been hugely misunderstanding what QUERY_STRING really is. Thanks a lot. Could you please also explain what (^|&) is?

Comment: `(^|&)` means query parameter is either at start OR after `&` same thing for `(&|$)` in the end which means that query parameter is followed by `&` OR end of line

Comment: oh, wow! I'm not a beginner in htaccess anymore. LOL Thanks to you Anubhava. You're the best! I'm glad that there are people like you on StackOverflow. When my knowledge base is large enough, I'll also contribute. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the generous words. So many folks here are doing their bit as I am. Really a great community here on SO.